# connection proxy error in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

While we get connection through hibernate we arise an error **connection proxy error** while we are using multiple connection's

Error message is like below statements

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: connnection proxy not usable after transaction completion at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:66) at $Proxy0.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) at com.indiamoney.api.advisor.dashboard.dao.impl.AdvisorDashboardDAOImpl.getCustemerRequestsCount(AdvisorDashboardDAOImpl.java:571) at com.indiamoney.api.advisor.dashboard.bo.AdvisorDashboardBO.getCustemerRequestsCount(AdvisorDashboardBO.java:226) at com.indiamoney.advisor.dashboard.action.AdvisorDashboardAction.dashboardDetails(AdvisorDashboardAction.java:307) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269) at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Nov 1, 2012 9:18:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters WARNING: Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored. Nov 1, 2012 9:18:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters WARNING: Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exception in a more tricky use case with hibernate 3.2.7/Spring 3.0.5 and ope-session-in-view filter. Presumably because of detached entity that was passed as param to a new thread and was updated in a separate transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Our system encounter this exception days ago. I tracked the BorrowedConnectionProxy.java and found this issue was caused by closing connection before hibernate use it:

We used Session.connection() to acquire the connection parasitized in session and closed it manaually. Under this circumstance the exception would be throwed out while any db-related methods on Session were invoked.

So please check and ensure a valid connection(in right status) is acquired by hibernate/session. Hope this is effective in your case.

Comment: "closed connection" also means the idle connections in the pool